# undefined value for empty database record

Tags: jquery, undefined

What is the best solution to `undefined` values being returned by database when the column is empty. Is there another way than having

```
if (!(databasevalue == 'undefined') || !(databasevalue == null)) {

    console.log(databasevalue)

} else {

    console.log('Value is empty')


}
```

This is ok if only few values can be empty what if multiple values can be empty DO i check each value if undefined or not then show the result

`UPDATE`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        id: "id"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        //check which data is undefined or not
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }


});
```

Is there are collective checking to see which data from the response is undefined or you need to check each have an if condition to check if the data is empty or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `&&` operator instead of `||` and `undefined` should not be in quotes

```
if (!(databasevalue == undefined) && !(databasevalue == null)) {
    console.log(databasevalue)
} else {
    console.log('Value is empty');
}
```

However simplest solution is you should check for `truthy` condition, Following condition is to check `databasevalu` has value

```
if (databasevalu) { //!!databasevalu
    console.log(databasevalue)
} else {
    console.log('Value is empty');
}
```

`!!` double-negation is used for conversion of condition to `boolean` instead of `truthy`

Comment: i can see that you and the Anik are different in this one i am confused `if(!databasevalue){
  // has value
}
else
{
  // empty
}` which is which

Comment: please see my comment again what is the correct one `if (databasevalu) { //!!databasevalu
    console.log(databasevalue)
}` or `if(!databasevalue){
  // has value
}`

Comment: let me check it for myself just to make it easy for me to digest the code brb

Comment: satpal thank you for the clarification i can somehow understand it now